# Copy .htaccess file conditionally depending on Netbeans configuration

Tags: php, web-services, netbeans

Is there a way to choose conditionally between files to copy depending on the used netbeans configuration. I have a different .htaccess file and need to copy it either to my local test server or the remote server. Which file to choose should be set by something like and #ifdef or other project configuration, so the right file is placed on the right server depending on the choosen configuration. Is that possible ?

Comment: Genuinely curious, why do you have a different test and production environment? What's preventing you from having the same .htaccess on both?  Not criticizing, just trying to learn.

Comment: Bascically I'm using different authentication on local and the remote server. As it's a shared hosting environment, I simply can't use exactly the same .htaccess files. If there's a better solution (something like an #ifdef or whatsoever), I would like to hear from. I'm relatively new in using netbeans, I usually do application coding (C# / C++ e.g.).

Comment: Not sure what the best answer is to that. I don't find myself changing my .htaccess very often once its set up so my next question would be, why are you changing it so often?

Comment: Well, I'm simply having a local and remote configuration with different setup. But as I want to have my project completely under version control, I need different .htaccess versions for local testing and remote deployment, mainly for using different authentication methods.